# Getting a list of Means by a parameter R

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
> head(chf)
  Admit.Day.of.Week Type.of.Admission          Patient.Disposition
1               SAT         Emergency         Skilled Nursing Home
2               FRI          Elective            Home or Self Care
3               FRI         Emergency Home w/ Home Health Services
4               MON         Emergency         Skilled Nursing Home
5               THU         Emergency            Home or Self Care
6               WED         Emergency         Skilled Nursing Home
  mean_los_dispo
1       8.553525
2       4.224193
3       5.789052
4       8.553525
5       4.224193
6       8.553525
```

I use the following command to get the column labled `mean_los_dispo`

```
# Mean LOS for each patient disposition
chf$mean_los_dispo <- ave(chf$Length.of.Stay, chf$Patient.Disposition,
                         FUN = mean)
```

What I want to do is set a variable to hold the value of the `mean_los_dispo` for each of the four different dispositions, for example

```
SNH = 8.553525
HSC = 4.224193
...
```

How would I go about doing this? I want to be able to eventually use `paste` or something similar to put the information in the title of a graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use paste. So for example, I created two variables, one with numbers (so your means) and another with characters (so your dispositions), and then I used paste to concatenate them:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<-c("a","b","c","d","e")

strs<-paste(b," = ",as.character(a),sep="")
```

This produces:

```
[1] "a = 1" "b = 2" "c = 3" "d = 4" "e = 5"
```

In your case you could do something like the following:

```
unique(paste(chf$Patient.Disposition," = ",as.character(chf$mean_los_dispo),sep=""))
```

The unique will get rid of all of the duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for your help, inside of the second solution you show using `unique` is it possible to first use something like `round()` to set `digists = 2`?

Comment: and that was much shorter than my long way of creating a daata.frame for each disposition.

Comment: Yup, just put it inside of as.character: `as.character(round(chf$mean_los_dispo,2))`